# Thumbnail Pagination ideas

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I need to write a script in PHP that will display 20 thumbnails at a time, and if you click on one of the thumbnails it will adjust to show a range of 20 thumbnails with the selected one in the center.  There are hundreds of thumbnails in the MySQL database so it needs to find the record and display 9 records before and 10 records after.

The idea I had involves 3 separate MySQL queries.  One to get the selected thumb, one to get the ones before and one to get the thumbnails after.

How can I do this with just one query?  My thumbnail database's key field is alphabetical so there is no number associated with the record, but I could add a integer ID field if I need to.

Comment: I guess that would only need to be 2 queries since I already have the selected thumbnail from the URL.  But I still think this could be done with 1 query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use limit to offset the result of your queries. With that and a simple count (to get the total elements in the table) you should be able to get your pages right =).

Here's the reference:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html

Also, I found this useful PHP/MySQL paging tutorial that uses limit

http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/paging-using-php.aspx

you'd only need to substract the 9 thumbnails and show 20 records to get the desired results.

good luck!

Comment: Good point, I was planning on using Limit, but I was thinking the wrong way.  Simple calculations could get me in the center.  Lol, I'm pre-coffee here, thanks...

Comment: We all have our pre-coffee moments =D

Comment: I think I'm discovering that in this case it's better to go ahead and use the two queries because the alternatives are slower.  I found this from someone that had the same issue.  http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?52,197366,197366#msg-197366